# Handling dynamic scripts that might be asynchronous

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous

We have an application that provides our users with the ability to write their own scripts at specific "hook" points. An example scenario is the following:

- We provide 2 form fields
- The user can add custom behavior to run on each "Focus Gained" and "Focus Lost" events
- The user writes a custom script where on "Focus Lost" of the first field, he executes some validation logic regarding that field's value
- If the validation is false, then our application must block the field change and force the selection to remain on the existing field until a valid value is provided

This scenario is easy to handle if the validation logic is something simple and synchronous like a regex match test. However what happens if a user adds some asynchronous logic (the validation rules might be provided by a web service for example)? How would you handle the `onFieldFocusLost` hook function then? Making it `async` will then force us to propagate the `await` chain all he way to the top of the call stack, up to the point where call sequence doesn't matter which might be a lot of layers up (that have already been implemented and will be a pain to change).

Note that we are using `Typescript` and compile it down to ES5 with a required compatibility with IE10+ (all `await` and `generator` shenanigans can be polyfilled as normal).

Minimal example:

```
// hook function whose implementation is provided by the user
function onFocusLost(field) {
  // implementation A
  return validRegex.test(field.value);

  // implementation B
  doXHR('/validRegex', 'GET', function(validRegex) {
    return validRegex.test(field.value);
  });
}

// hook function called by our application
inputField.addEventListener('focus-lost', function() {
  if (!onFocusLost(inputField)) {
    forceFocusToRemainOnField(inputField);
    return;
  }
  giveFocusToNextField(); // this must not be called if the user's onFocusLost logic returns false (synchronously or not)
});
```

Comment: Could you add a [mcve] please?

Comment: The described scenario is pretty explanatory, but here you go

Comment: You cant `return` from a callback!

Comment: I know, this is only for explaining what the goal is. It is not totally valid javascript

Comment: Add a callback function they can call if using async that has a pass/fail input.

Comment: Please explain how you would do that without adding all the logic following `onFocusLost` inside the callback

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to check if the hook returns a Promise, and if so, block the field until the promise returns:

```
 inputField.addEventListener('focus-lost', async function(){
    const hook: boolean | Promise<boolean>  = onFocusLost();
    if(hook instanceof Promise){
      forceFocusToRemainOnField(inputField);
      alert("We are checking your input! Please wait");
      hook = await hook;
    }
    if(hook){
      //release field somehow
    } else {
     forceFocusToRemainOnField(inputField);
    }
 });
```

So a hook may look like this:

```
 async function hook(){
   const res = await fetch("someapi");
   return res === "success";
}
```

Comment: As explained in the question description, that's what we have implemented but this required all the callstack up to that point to become awaitable which can go 10 layers up

Comment: @konstantine and whats your expected result now? Some magic code that makes async code sync? That does not exist...

Comment: I am laying down a problem and asking for a solution according to some requirements. If no such solution exists, that is also an acceptable answer.

Comment: @konstantine the solution would be refactoring. However, why do you even need to await it 10 layers up? Is there some additional logic? Cant that be triggered by `focusToRemainOnField` and its counterpart? Does that really need to be async?

Comment: There is a lot of extra logic that has not been outlined here of course. The application is complex and has a lot of stuff that can happen in the background while the user is moving around form fields. Also the user, since he's told that he can write custom scripts logic in Javascript in a browser context, will expect to be able to do asynchronous logic since JS is all about that now.

Comment: @konstantine its hard to help without having an overview of that code... good luck with refactoring :)